# RulePlot but with integers instead of colors?

Tags: cellular-automata

I would like to produce something like the output of a `RulePlot` for a `CellularAutomaton`, but where the output state is an integer instead of a color. I mean something like this, which I made in photoshop:

[image]

Is it possible to do this using `RulePlot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post-process `RulePlot` output to add text labels:

```
ClearAll[addLabels]
addLabels[rp_, labels_] := Module[{l = RotateRight@ labels }, 
  Replace[rp, p: {_EdgeForm, {{GrayLevel[x_], Rectangle[a_, b_]}} }  :>
    {p, If[x < .5, GrayLevel[1], GrayLevel[0]], 
     Text[First[l = RotateLeft[l]], Mean[{a, b}]]}, ∞] ]
```

**Examples:**

```
bf = BooleanFunction[{True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False}] ;
rp = RulePlot[bf, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
labels = RandomInteger[10, 8]
```

> {1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6}

```
addLabels[rp, labels]
```

[image]

```
rp2 = RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{679458, 3}], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
labels2 = RandomInteger[10, 27]
```

> {1, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 6, 0, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 10, 1, 6, 0, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4}

```
addLabels[rp2, labels2]
```

[image]